# Connect Heroku postgres from localclient

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to connet with

```
psql -h ec2-23-23-227-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com -U igcmskkpsx igcmskkpsx
```

but it answer:

```
psql: no se pudo conectar con el servidor: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        ¿Está el servidor en ejecución en el servidor «ec2-23-23-227-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com» y aceptando
        conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto 5432?
```

Please any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku dosen't allow access from an external client while the account is free; I had to use the cleanMysql plugin to access from my local navicat

Comment: Any chance you can  cite the page on heroku.com that states this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the port with -P porthere when connecting if its not runnin gon the default port.

Comment: This can depend on the database, it would be specified within the connection string to the database. Additionally you should be able to run: heroku pg:psql or heroku pg:psql COLOR (where color is the db color within the config variable)